# DOMMouseScroll, event.originalEvent.detail always returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse, mousewheel

I am working on a simple JS/jQuery script to detect the mouse wheel scrolling.

Everything works as expected on most browsers biding to "mousewheel", but on Firefox I have to use "DOMMouseScroll".

The problem is that event.originalEvent.detail (when called from Firefox) always returns 0. This way, it is impossible for me to know when the user is scrolling up or down, and I am sure that this is not the intended behavior.

This is my code, if that may matter:

```
$j(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(delay) return;
    delay = true;
    setTimeout(function(){delay = false},2000)

    var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;
    window.alert(event.originalEvent.detail); // to check the value
    var a= document.getElementsByClassName('wpb_revslider_element');
    if(wd <= 0) {
      for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
        var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
        if(t >= 40) break;
      }
    }
    else {
      for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
        if(t < -20) break;
      }
    }

    if(i >= 0 && i < a.length) {
      $j('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
      });
    }
  });
})();
```

Do you have any other suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `wheel` event instead, official docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel). The `mousewheel` event is deprecated. Checkout the original docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel).

```
$(document).on('wheel', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (delay) return;
  delay = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    delay = false
  }, 2000)
  var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;
  window.alert(event.originalEvent.detail); // to check the value
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('wpb_revslider_element');
  if (wd <= 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
      if (t >= 40) break;
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
      if (t < -20) break;
    }
  }

  if (i >= 0 && i < a.length) {
    $j('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
    });
  }
});
```

> **Update :**

The `deltaX` and `deltaY` properties are supported in `Chrome`, `Firefox` and other notable browsers, just check the docs of `wheel` event mentioned above. Based on your requirement you can change the value you want to pick. The actual values in the different browser may vary, but the behavior is same. Just check if less than or greater than zero as you are already doing.

```
var wd = event.originalEvent.deltaY; // for vertical scrolling 
  // For horizontal scroll change check `event.originalEvent.deltaX` value

// positive value of wd above will mean scrolled down and 
//negative will mean scrolled down.
```

Hope this helped!

> **Another Update**

There seems to be a Caveat Using the `wheel` event on Safari browser

As per OP's opinion

> Doesn't work on Safari so I use the old function with "mousewheel" on
>   Safari and the new "wheel" on all other browsers. For readers, just
>   note that "wheel" coordinates and "mousewheel" coordinates are
>   opposite, so while scrolling down is positive on "mousewheel", it's
>   negative on "wheel" and vice-versa

Comment: Thank you. That works as a replacement for my current function, but on Firefox the wd value is still 0.
Plus, does "wheel" have any compatibility issue, since it's a new standard?

Comment: It will work on all modern browser if you see the compatibility table on the docs page and `mousewheel` is deprecated. So that shouldn't be used anyway.

Comment: Are you getting `wheelDeltax` and `wheelDeltaY` ?

Comment: Great! That works now! Doesn't work on Safari so I use the old function with "mousewheel" on Safari and the new "wheel" on all other browsers.
For readers, just note that "wheel" coordinates and "mousewheel" coordinates are opposite, so while scrolling down is positive on "mousewheel", it's negative on "wheel" and vice-versa

Comment: Thanks for Pointing it out @FrCr , I consider this question still open then. Will update if anything helpful I find out regarding it.

Comment: One suggestion for now would be to write a wrapper method over this event. Just pass it the event object and let it handle all the compatibility issues. Sometimes the Browser vendor do not update their engines with the new norms. That's why developer always need to write fallback code. Its not always hunky dory when dealing in Web Technologies with so many browsers to handle. We all have been through that :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution for event.originalEvent.detail value but if you want to know if the user scroll up or down, just store scroll position on scroll and on mousewheel DOMMouseScroll, check if the new scroll position is greater than the old one.

Exemple :

```
var oldScrollY = 0;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    oldScrollY = window.scrollY;
});

$j(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    if (oldScrollY > window.scrollY) {
       console.log('scroll up');
    } else {
       console.log('scroll down');
    }
});
```

Comment: On Firefox, this function always executes the "down" part even if I go up. That is even stranger because it really detects the scroll, not the wheel movement, and the page goes up for sure if I scroll up!

Comment: can't test wheel event, since I don't have a mouse on my computer, but I think Prabodh M has the answer to your problem